# Why did my radiator stop heating after turning it down for a while?

Tags: radiator

I turned down my radiator the other day & now there is no heat in it at all. I've bled it with no success. The intake pipe at the other end of the radiator is warm but the radiator itself is not.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: More info about your system. Hot water? Steam? One pipe or two?

Comment: When you said "*I've bled it with no success*". Does that mean nothing came out when you bled it, or that bleeding it didn't solve the problem?